# How to fix Django autocomplete_fields jquery error?

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'm using Django autocomplete_fields feature but I have a problem with Jquery TypeError: $element.select2 is not a function

Under django development server works perfectly as spected but when I deploy the code on a server to test jquery is not working and I get

VM106 inlines-nested.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

autocomplete.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: $element.select2 is not a function

I'm using Django 2.1 + gunicorn + docker + nginx to deploy the code

My code in admin.py is

```py
class CityModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class ProfileAdminModel(NestedModelAdmin):
    #form = ProfileCustomForm
    inlines = [DescriptionInline, AddressInline, CommentInline]
    autocomplete_fields = ['city','profession','location',
                           'user', 'branch1', 'branch2',
                           'branch3', 'institution1', 'institution2']



admin.site.register(City,CityModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdminModel)
```